# Defer componentDidUpdate, make it execute after browser paints

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs

I have a `Dashboard` component which has some real DOM operations (it uses some charting libraries and d3.js) in `componentDidUpdate()`.

These operations may cost hundreds of milliseconds in total and I just noticed that when switching pages, all the `componentDidUpdate`s are executed **before** the browser paints. The sequence is:

1. Unmout current page
2. Mount Dashboard (and its children)
3. Dispatch Redux actions to fetch some data
4. componentDidUpdates (of Dashboard and its children)
5. Browser paints the Dashboard (users can see the dashboard page now)

I found [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2659) indicates that this is an intentional behavior. But this behavior makes my app feels laggy. Because when switching page from `Foo` to `Dashboard`, users will stuck on `Foo` and have to wait around 0.6s to see the `Dashboard` page shows.

My current workaround is to wrap those DOM operations with `setTimeout`:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  setTimeout(() => this.expensiveDOMOperations(), 0)
}
```

This solution works, these operations are deferred and executed after the browser paints. But there are tons of `setTimeout` that I just don't feel right.

So my question is, is there any better / more elegant solution for this?

I also have some other questions if anyone knows the answers:

1. Does the `setTimeout(..., 0)` guarantee that the code will be executed *after* the browser paints? (In Vue.js there is a [`nextTick()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) helper to do this)
2. Will this behavior change in React Fiber?

Comment: How many times does `render()` run when going from `Foo` to `Dashboard`?

Comment: @Chris 1, but after that Dashboard will dispatch 4 actions in total and each of them will cause a re-render

Comment: So it renders 5 times?

Comment: I just removed these actions to test and the `render()` only executes 1 time

Comment: @Chris In my real code it's 5, but the 2~5 `render`s are just to fill data to the Dashboard.

Comment: Well the problem is that `componentDidUpdate` will run each time there is a re-render. Which is bad on its own, especially if it's an expensive algorithm. You need to figure out a way to prevent that from happening. Maybe add a flag which is toggled when the 4 actions are finished.

Comment: I do have some guard conditions to prevent this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142459/discussion-between-chris-and-codincat).